Unable to set value of Material UI datepicker from browser using query selector
I am using the Material UI v5 library for DatePicker.
I am trying to set the value of date picker (Material UI v5) from the browser using query selector, it vanishes when I click on the browser or tab button.
Eg. This is my element of DatePicker from MUI X 5
<input aria-invalid="false" id=":rj:" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm" 
    type="tel" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd 
    css-1x51dt5-MuiInputBase-input-MuiInput-input" value="">

I am trying to set value using this from the console
document.querySelector("#\\:rj\\:").value = "2024-04-03 13:25" 

Current Behaviour : Value are showing on the Date Picker using this querySelector but when I click on the browser or Tab button value is gone from the datePicker input.
Expected Behaviour : when I set the value from console using these querySelector, I want that value will show on that datePicker input.
